# Module not found Error: No module name matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using **python 3.7**, windows OS.I successfully installed **matplotlib** using
**pip install matplotlib** It worked fine if commands run from command prompt but shows the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'` if I run it from my regular IDLE.
every suggestion is appreciated .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st check on which environment you're running you scripts

```
conda info --envs
```

it will give you your active environment, and run

```
pip list
```

will give you all active packages installed.

even if that doesn't help than create new environment

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.6
conda activate myenv
```

and install matplotlib again

```
pip install matplotlib
```